# What would happen if monero were to switch to RandomJS mining algo?

Tags: mining, randomjs

There seems to be talk of switching to randomJS for mining. What would this affect? Is there even a gpu miner for something like this and is it even gpu minable?

What's so great about RandomJS vs every other new mining algo that's relatively new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with literally every static algorithm is that sooner or later someone will find a way how to build a chip just for that purpose, since every algorithm has its own requirements on hardware and on general purpose machines uses just a fraction of available resources. ASIC manufacturers remove all unneeded stuff and create circuits just for one algorithm into silicone. These chips are pretty dumb and cannot perform anything else than their only algorithm, they cannot even be programmed otherwise and when there is just some small adjustment they become useless.

RandomJS (among other attempts) creates random code which has to be executed and a miner does not even have the time to optimise FPGAs for it, but the best ASIC to run it is an CPU (or GPU). The "problem" currently is that there is no full (optimised) JavaScript interpreter for GPU chips yet, but I'm pretty sure it will ship soon, at least for newer GPU generations.

RandomJS would make manually applied algorithm changes for mining obsolete which is just good for the future of the project and the other aims which do so with the block size or min-fees. Manual protocol changes should be the last option, since every time they are applied they also offer new attack vectors.